# Cannot name JuMP variables after they are successfully read in

Tags: julia-jump

I have read in vectors of tuples into variables with the below:

```
@variable(model, x[flowslist] >= 0.0)
@variable(model, y[edgelist] >= 0.0)
@variable(model, z[supplylist] >=0.0)
```

But then hit an error when I try to change the name of these variables:

```
name(x)
```

Error returned is as follows:

```
MethodError: no method matching name(::JuMP.Containers.DenseAxisArray{VariableRef, 1, Tuple{Vector{Tuple{String15, String15, String31}}}, Tuple{JuMP.Containers._AxisLookup{Dict{Tuple{String15, String15, String31}, Int64}}}})
```

MethodError. Any idea what caused this or how to fix it? I would normally assume that if the variables are read in then there is no problem as such.